# How to get the url prefixes asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

I have a ASP.NET MVC application which will work on a IIS7.
I don't know the final URL yet, and that's the problem.

I want to get the URL-Parts between the Top-level-domain and my controller.

For examople: `http://www.mydomain.com/myApplication/MyController/ControllerMethod`should return `/myApplication/MyController/`

This should also be possible, if the application is called via the standard method, for example `http://www.mydomain.com/myApplication`.

The Problem is that with my method it works perfectly if the full controller- and methodname is in the url, but as soon as there is only the controller name and the route takes the default `index`-method or there is no controller/method and the route takes the default controller/method, it will fail because my code puts wrong output.

I thought about hardcoding the controller-name and make a if-then-else orgy, but this doesn't seem very professional...

Maybe anyone of you has got an Idea.

Here's my function:

```
String segments = Request.Url.Segments;
System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
String lastSegment = "";
int i= 0;

do
{
     builder.Append(segments[i]);
     lastSegment = segments[i++];
} while(!lastSegment.Equals("Home") && !lastSegment.Equals("Home/") && i < segments.Length);
return builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Url class to build the Urls for you [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Ooh, now I feel kind of embarassed... Thank you :)